# Operar medias y graficar en R desde un csv con datos listados

Tags: r

Tengo un fichero de datos que, minimizado (el fichero original contiene más rondas y niveles de "Contenido"), responde más o menos a la siguiente estructura ([datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcwxhns109ewat8/data.csv?dl=0)):

```
Ronda  Contenido  Salida
1        0        [1,1,1,1]
1        0        [1,1,1,1]
1        0.1      [1,1,1,1]
1        0.1      [1,1,1,1]
1        0.2      [1,1,1,1]
1        0.2      [1,1,1,1]
2        0        [1,0,2,1]
2        0        [2,0,1,1]
2        0.1      [2,1,1,0]
2        0.1      [2,1,1,0]
2        0.2      [3,1,0,0]
2        0.2      [4,0,0,0]
```

Me gustaría (aprender a) obtener la media e intervalo de confidencia al 95% del primer valor de la lista en la columna "Salida", para cada combinación de Ronda y Contenido. En el ejemplo obtendríamos algo así:

```
Ronda    Contenido   Media Salida
1        0           1
1        0.1         1
1        0.2         1
2        0           1.5
2        0.1         2
2        0.2         3.5
```

La idea es generar un gráfico que represente "Ronda" en el eje x, "Media+CI95% de Salida" en el eje y, para cada valor de "Contenido". Tenía pensado utilizar un código similar al que sigue, pero claro, el tratamiento de la columna "Salida" debe ser distinto:

```
y <- datos$Salida
z <- datos$Contenido
g <- datos$Ronda
z = factor(z, levels = c(0, 0.1, 0.2))
data <- data.frame(y,z,g)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales) 
data %>%
  group_by(g, z) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),                             #Estimación de la media
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             #Error estandar de la estimación de la media. 
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      #Techo del intervalo. 
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%  #Piso del intervalo al 95%.
  ggplot(aes(x = g, y = media, color = clave)) +
  labs(title=mytitle1) +
  geom_point() +                                        #Para que genere una salida gráfica cuando sólo hay un data point.
  geom_line(aes(group = clave), size=1) +                       #Las líneas que unen los puntos de cada grupos xz
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup,               #Intervalor al 95% para cada punto. 
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.3) + 
  #theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Round", y = "Mean+CI", color = "Model") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("0", "0.1","0.2"), values = c("blue","red","purple")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))
```

---

Nota: la columna Salida aparece así en el dataframe porque se trata de listas de enteros creadas con Python.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué tal pyring? No me queda claro el alcance de tu pregunta ¿Se trata de  como "extraer" el primer valor de la columna `Salida`? ¿`Salida` que es, una vector o una lista?

Comment: @Patricio Moracho hola! Exacto. La media solo la deseo realizar sobre el primer valor de la columna. He añadido los resultados de medias que obtendríamos en el ejemplo dado.

Comment: Ahora bien, el fichero ¿ya has logrado importarlo? si es así, podrías compartir la estructura del `data.frame`, por ejemplo `str(df)` o mucho mejor `dput(head(df)`.

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho, acabo de añadir un link a un archivo de datos que contiene una estructura similar al csv original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu archivo CSV no es del todo amigable para utilizarlo directamente, la columna `Salida` parece ser una lista de valores. Lo primero que podemos hacer es importarlo y estudiar la columna más en detalle:

```
data <- read.csv("C:/Tmp/data.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Contamos cantidad de , 
n <- unique(lengths(regmatches(data$Salida, gregexpr(",",  data$Salida)))) + 1
n

[1] 8
```

Hemos importado el archivo tal como está, luego contamos la cantidad de `,` que tienen todas las observaciones de `Salida` y vemos si la columna es heterogénea en cuanto a la cantidad de valores. Puedo verificar que todas las observaciones de `Salida` tienen 8 posibles valores, lo cual nos allana el camino para "expander" las cadenas separadas por comas en columnas reales.

```
# Primero quitamos ambos corchetes
data$Salida <- gsub('\\[|\\]', '', data$Salida)

# Separamos los 8 valores posibles de Salida en una matrix de nro.filas x 8
m <- matrix(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(data$Salida, "\\,"))), byrow= T, ncol=n)
colnames(m) <- paste0("V",1:n)

# Combinamos la matriz al data.frame original
data <- cbind(data, m)
data <- data[, -4] # Borramos la columna Salida

head(data)

  X Ronda Contenido V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1 1     1         0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2 2     1         0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
3 3     1         0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
4 4     2         0  2  1  2  0  1  0  1  1
5 5     2         0  1  1  0  2  2  0  0  2
6 6     2         0  1  1  1  1  2  0  1  1
```

Como puedes observar, hemos transformado la columna salida en 8 columnas llamada `V1..8`, ahora, usar la primera o cualquier otra es trivial.

Todo lo anterior, usando R base, pero si tienes `tidyverse` se hace increiblemente más simple y claro:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
    mutate(Salida = gsub('\\[|\\]', '', Salida)) %>% # Quitamos corchetes
    separate(Salida, into=paste0("V",1:8))           # Separamos Salida en columnas
```

**NOTA**: Todo esto si quieres resolverlo mediante **R**, lo cierto es que en este ejemplo, dónde la cantidad de valores es siempre fija, podrías usar cualquier otra herramienta de reemplazo para quitar los corchetes `[]` con lo cual te terminaría quedando un simple archivo CSV perfectamente importable.

Comment: Como no es R lo agrego como comentario: Si tienes acceso a bash (con Linux, macOS, Windows con Linux Services for Windows) podrías corregir el archivo con la siguiente línea `awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub("\\[|\\]", "", $i) } 1' data.csv > output.csv`, donde `data.csv` es el nombre del archivo problemático y `output.csv` el nombre del archivo resultante. Esto elimina todos los corchetes. La ventaja sobre una solución es R es que es prácticamente instantaneo, aún para archivo enormes. Es feo, pero efectivo.

Comment: Gracias @mpaladino. Respuesta muy útil. Sí, utilizo cygwin

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho, el código funciona muy bien para el propósito

Answer (score 2):

> Aunque con los datos ya no es relevante conservo la respuesta porque sirve para otro problema: extraer elementos dentro de una lista en un data.frame.

Algo así serán tus datos?

```
data.frame(Ronda = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
           Contenido = c(0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2)) -> foo
foo$Salida <- list (c (1,1,1,1), c (1,1,1,1), c (1,1,1,1), c (1,1,1,1), c (1,1,1,1), c (1,1,1,1), c (1,0,2,1), c (2,0,1,1), c (2,1,1,0), c (2,1,1,0), c (3,1,0,0), c (4,0,0,0))`
```

De modo que:

```
str(foo)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ Ronda : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Conte : num  0 0 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0 0 0.1 0.1 ...
$ Salida:List of 12
..$ : num  1 1 1 1
..$ : num  1 1 1 1
..$ : num  1 1 1 1
..$ : num  1 1 1 1
..$ : num  1 1 1 1
..$ : num  1 1 1 1
..$ : num  1 0 2 1
..$ : num  2 0 1 1
..$ : num  2 1 1 0
..$ : num  2 1 1 0
..$ : num  3 1 0 0
..$ : num  4 0 0 0
```

Sería muy importante que siguieras la recomendación de @Patricio Moracho y subieras un ejemplo de tus datos. Si salidas es una lista de listas en lugar de una lista de vectores (como en `foo`) la solución podría no funcionar. 
Si tus datos tienen esta estructura podrías crear una nueva columna con el primer elemento de cada lista de `Salida` con:

```
foo$salida1 <- sapply(foo$Salida, `[`, 1)
```

> `sapply()` pasa una función por una lista y `foo$Salida` es una lista. Dentro de un data.frame, pero lista al fin. Al ser `sapply()` se simplifica el output, convirtiéndolo en vector. 
>   `[` es una función de subsetting que extrae valores por posición, en este caso el valor con índice 1.

Con esos datos podrías hacer:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  foo %>% 
  group_by(Ronda, Contenido) %>% 
  summarise(media = mean(salida1), 
            desvio = sd(salida1),
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(Ronda = as.factor(Ronda), Contenido = as.factor(Contenido)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Ronda, y = media, color = Contenido)) +   
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.3)) +                       
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup,            
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),                      
                position=position_dodge(0.3), 
                width = 0.3)
```

Que produce:

[image: Gráfico de pyring 4]

Comment: Gracias @mpaladino, acabo de añadir un link en el artículo para tener acceso a la estructura de los datos de la columna "Salida", que es con la que no se operar.La idea del gráfico es exáctamente ésta, quizá utilizando geom_line para unir esas medias. Pero esta es la idea.

Comment: En ese caso la solución de @Patricio Moracho es la más directa. De todos modos, ya con los datos, agregué una solución alternativa con `bash`

Comment: Gracias, utilizo cygwin